# SQL bin all events into 3 month buckets

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am trying to create a 3 month lookahead type table. So for example any event where `LAST_DAY(event_date) = '2021-01-01'` (i.e Jan-2021) will be valid in February-2021 and March-2021 as well.

For each event, I want another row for the 2 months after which it happens. Example below:

Given data that looks like this:

| event_date | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| Jan-21 | A |
| Feb-21 | B |
| Jan-21 | A |
| Jun-21 | C |
| Mar-21 | D |

I want to create some thing that looks like this:

| event_date | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| Jan-21 | A |
| Feb-21 | A |
| Mar-21 | A |
| Feb-21 | B |
| Mar-21 | B |
| Apr-21 | B |
| Jun-21 | C |
| Jul-21 | C |
| Aug-21 | C |
| Mar-21 | D |
| Apr-21 | D |
| May-21 | D |

Kind of stuck on how to achieve this. You can assume that the `event_date` is a valid datetime field here. I've tried a few different things to no avail. I would usually use a window function for something like this with `PRECEDING` and `FOLLOWING` limits here but `LEAD`, `LAG` type functions only allow you to set 1 offset and not a range of offset.

Any help is appreciated. Working in PSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in two steps:

1. Group the data (e.g. A appears twice, but you want to compute that only once since both rows of A are in this case identical)
2. Generate the new data with additional rows for next month and the month after that

Step one is simple given your example, in a more elaborate situation you might group data with `group by`, here a `distinct` is sufficient:

```
select distinct event_date, customer_id from table;
```

This is the basis and the other two generated information per row rely on this data. Maybe you could create a view for this and reuse it. I will do so and call it `view`, but you could as well simply use the SQL statement as is. Think of it as `view` is equal to `select distinct event_date, customer_id from table`.

The second step can be done by adding the data for next month, and similarly the data the month after that. A union comes to mind.

```
select event_date, customer_id from view
UNION 
select next_month(event_date), customer_id from view
UNION
select after_next_month(event_date), customer_id from view
```

Now we are left with date arithmetic, you want to calculate the next month and the one after that.

If that is ok for you I would suggest you merely add 30 to the date, e.g. `select event_date + 30, customer_id from view` and `select event_date + 60, customer_id from view`.

Otherwise it should not be too difficult to do the appropriate date arithmetic, see [Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: Just a quick comment on the date arithmetic, better to do something like `date_add(month, 1, event_date)` since adding 30 days can get you into trouble with edge cases (Jan has 31 days, feb has 28 so it can be leapfrogged)

Answer (score 1):

We can use a calendar table approach here:

```sql
WITH months AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', dd)::date AS month
    FROM generate_series ('2021-01-01'::timestamp,
                          '2021-12-01'::timestamp,
                          '1 month'::interval) dd
)

SELECT DISTINCT m.month, t.customer_id
FROM months m
INNER JOIN yourTable t
    ON m.month BETWEEN t.event_date AND t.event_date + interval '2 month'
ORDER BY
    t.customer_id, m.month;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The idea is to join the calendar table of all dates to your table of events on the condition that the months match, or the former's month be 1 or 2 months later.  Note that I assume that each "month" can be represented by the full date at the first of the month.  You should ideally always be working with proper dates here.